# Should I initialize a Box2D World per Level?

Tags: libgdx, box2d

I'm using a LevelManager to load Tiled maps in my libGDX game, which stores:

**Static:**

- final `Size` of map in Tiles
- final `Size` of map in Pixels
- final `Size` of an individual tile
- `TiledMap ACTIVE_MAP`
- `World WORLD`

When the map is loaded, it creates a new World and stores it in the static `WORLD`, later populating it with static bodies based on objects found in the map's Collision layer.

My reasoning for using static is down to the fact that logically, only one map will be playable at any one time, however I've got it in my head that only constants and singletons should be static, so this feels strange for me. Is there a better, more efficient way of handling this?

**Should I have one World per Level, or a global World independent of what TiledMap is active?**

In other words, should I initialize `WORLD` once and leave it as is, making it final, or continue what I am doing and initialize it as a new World whenever a new TiledMap is loaded?

**How do I correctly dispose of all bodies within the World, essentially clearing it?**

I'm going to have to do this every time I load a new map, regardless of whether or not `WORLD` is global.

Comment: `constants and singletons should be static`, this is not true, constants are `static final`. Static has nothing to do with constant, it is just a shared variable all across your `LevelManager` class, its value can change. If you follow java naming conventions you should name it `activeMap` not `ACTIVE_MAP`, since its not final, just static. Also in java you don't *have to* dispose anything. It has an automated garbage collector.

Comment: When I say dispose, I mean clear the world of all bodies, otherwise when I load a new level, bodies from the previous level will persist. Also, I meant static final, and while this question isn't about naming conventions, I thank you for pointing that one out, and will modify it.

Comment: There is a `world.dispose()` function for that. Does it not do what you require ? If not, you could iterate through every single body and call `world.destroyBody(body)`, even though I am pretty sure that is what `world.dispose()` should be doing and perhaps even more.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. The [dispose method](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/extensions/gdx-box2d/gdx-box2d/src/com/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/World.java#L947) causes my game to crash. I have overcome this however, and will provide details in an answer.

Comment: Probably because you are disposing the Player's body itself, since it is in the same world.

Comment: There is no documentation regarding World disposal, and I don't think the dispose method for World works as it should or does what it seems. That's not important though, I shouldn't need to dispose the world at all.

Comment: Put a break point after world.dispose(), run in debug mode and you will see that it is not the reason your game is crashes. As I said, I am pretty sure it crashes because you are not re-initializing the player's body, which get disposed after calling world.dispose(), or something along those lines.

Comment: Actually, as I load the map before adding any bodies, essentially clearing the World (making the call to World.dispose()), the crash happens whenever jniCreateBody is called internally - I can't create a body within a world that has been disposed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took some time to think about the issue and realized that <strike>logically, there is no purpose for disposing the World or re-initializing it whenever a new Level is loaded</strike> it seems a lot better to dispose and reinitialize the world when a new Level is loaded - thanks to @Shiro for helping me see this. I won't have to manually clear all of the World's bodies, forces, etc.

I created a WorldManager class which contains the World and a method to "clear" it:

```
public final class WorldManager {

    public static World world;

    private WorldManager() {}

    public static void clearWorld() {
        if (world != null) {
            world.dispose();
        }

        world = new World(new Vector2(0, 0), true);
    }
}
```

In my LevelManager class, before loading a specified level, I make a call to `WorldManager.clearWorld()`

Comment: [destroyBodies](http://i.gyazo.com/13e59f65eb99327329646f6096d132ab.png) destroys joints as well. I am pretty sure what you are doing is exactly what `world.dispose()` does. Are you sure you are re-instantiating your world, after you dispose it ? `world = new World(new Vector2(0, -10), true);`

Comment: As I said, I shouldn't need to reinitialize it. I don't see the purpose of doing so. `World#dispose()` [doesn't do this](http://i.imgur.com/i5LQWTA.png).

Comment: This is a `native` function that calls code written in C language. You can clearly see that the world gets deleted. `delete world;`. So yes, you **should** need to re-instantiate your `world` object. world.dispose() destroys all bodies and the world instance itself.

Comment: I understand where you're coming from now. Thanks!